# What is the space between -10 promoter sites and start sites (+1)

Tags: dna, molecular-genetics, t7-promoter

Between the transcriptional start site of a gene and the -10 promoter region there is always a space of around 10 nucleotides, what is this space function and purpose?

Do you see the space between operator and promoter.. that is what I am referring to, even without an operator it is usually still there

Also, if I want to insert a specific promoter into a vector backbone, how much space should be between the promoter -10 and +1 transcription start site? Is it always 10 bp?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you mean. Are you referring to the transcription start site  or the translation start site? I guess you mean the former, but it isn't very clear from your question.

Comment: I would say that you are referring to the kozak sequence
<https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kozak_consensus_sequence>

Comment: Transcription start site

Answer (score 1):

By "start site", do you refer to the "start codon"?

I think the spacing you are referring to is the [**5' UTR**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_prime_untranslated_region#Length).

> The 5′ untranslated region (5′ UTR) (also known as a Leader Sequence or Leader RNA) is the region of an mRNA that is directly upstream from the initiation codon. This region is important for the regulation of translation of a transcript by differing mechanisms in viruses, prokaryotes and eukaryotes

Have a look at the wikipedia article for more information about its roles.

The 5' UTR is typically 3 to 10 nucleotides long in prokaryotes but can be much longer (up to several thousands of nucleotides) in eukaryotes. On which species did you notice this spacing of about 10 nucleotides?

Comment: I *think* the OP is referring to the transcription start site, not the ATG. Otherwise, their mention of a promoter doesn't make much sense.

Comment: No, the 5' UTR would include the -10, -35, Shine-Dalgarno and other operator motifs. The OP is specifically asking what the ~10 base pairs between the -10 box and the actual start codon are for.
As far as I'm aware, as a molecular biologist, the site merely serves as a spacer to allow the relevant enzymes to dock with the nucleic acids correctly. You have to bear in mind that just because the ribosomes binding site is only 6-8 bases, the actual amount of DNA that it's occluding will be considerably more potentially.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was referring to, the base pairs between the transcriptional start site which usually includes the 5' UTR and the upstream (-10) part of the promoter. There doesn't seem to be much information around what exactly this section function and purpose is. Even with an operator in a prokaryotic sequence, the space is still there...

Comment: @condo1234 OK, but please *edit* your question and clarify.

Comment: The major reason I am asking is say if I want to insert a specific promoter into a vector backbone, how much space should be between the promoter -10 and +1 transcription start site? Does it always have to be -10?

Comment: The question itself is unclear. However I guess that the answer, as it is written right now, looks as if it is requesting clarification. It appears more like a comment.